# Example: uncountable set having a limit point but no condensation points?

Tags: general-topology, limits

Recall that a point $x$ in a topological space $X$ is a *limit point* of a subset $A$ when each neighborhood of $x$ contains points of $A$ distnct from $x$; and $x$ is a *condensation point* of $A$ when each neighborhood of $x$ contains uncountably many points of $A$.

It is well known that: (a) in a $T_1$-space, each neighborhood of a limit point of $A$ necessarily contains infinitely many points of $A$; (b) a condensation point is a limit point; and (c) all but countably many points of an uncountable subset of a second-countable space are condensation points of that subset.

In $\mathbb{R}$, the subset $A = \{1/n : n = 1, 2, 3, \dots\} \cup (1, 2)$ has 0 as a limit point pf $A$ that is *not* a condensation point of $A$; but $A$ has uncountably many condensation points.

What is an example of an uncountable subset $A$ of a Hausdorff space $X$ having no condensation points in $X$ but having limit points in $X$?

Comment: "A limit point of $A$ contains..." Presumably, you mean any open neighborhood of a limit point?

Comment: Take $X=$ the ordinal $\omega_1$ and $A$ the subset of all $\alpha\in X$ such that $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal.

Comment: You can certainly find spaces like The Long Line which have uncountable discrete subspaces, so you can use something like that to construct an example - just add a countable set that converges to $0$ and add it to the discrete uncountable set. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)

Comment: @murray: Correction, that should have been 'take $A$ to be the subset of all *non*-limit ordinals'.  Then every limit ordinal is a limit point of $A$, but there can't be any condensation points because every point in $X$ has countable open neighborhoods.

Comment: @JohnDoe Why not just take $A=X$?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: Yes, I noted that about second-countable spaces already in my original post.

Comment: @murray my mistake